# How to implement elasticsearch custom similarity plugin?

Tags: java, lucene, indexing, elasticsearch, querydsl

I need to override Lucene Default Similarity Class which is used by Elasticsearch for indexing and searching. On searching net, I found some similar implementations which are doing similar things. My difficulty is that I have no idea of how to actually implement this in my code. I found some resources:

https://github.com/tlrx/elasticsearch-custom-similarity-provider

```
curl -XPOST 'http://host:port/tweeter/' -d '
{
  "settings": {
    "similarity": {
      "index": {
        "type": "org.elasticsearch.index.similarity.CustomSimilarityProvider"
      },
      "search": {
        "type": "org.elasticsearch.index.similarity.CustomSimilarityProvider"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

I'm not able to understand how can i use this line directly during indexing so that my default similarity changes to this custom similarity.

**org.elasticsearch.index.similarity.CustomSimilarityProvider**

Can anyone please tell me how I can do this ? I tried running the same thing on my machine but it's not working for me. Do I need to modify this line or path ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Comment: it probably was not.   He wants to know how to inject his own Java-written similarity class/provider, as opposed to the various ones Elasticsearch provides out of the box.

Answer (score 4):

The link that your posted https://github.com/tlrx/elasticsearch-custom-similarity-provider is for older version of elasticsearch.

Based on the elasticsearch taste plugin https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-taste, I made a simple custom similarity plugin for version 2.1.1 with detailed explanations of all the steps 
https://github.com/stefansavev/elasticsearch-custom-similarity-example. I kept it simple to only three java files and one config file. I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

The json that you posted is the one that creates an index, using the [create index api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html). In the same request you can provide settings, mappings and so on for that index. Among the settings, you can register a custom similarity.

Once you created the index you need to actually index documents into it using the [index api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html).

Also, since 0.90 you can also configure a custom similarity [per field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#_configuring_similarity_per_field) through the mappings.